# What's the difference between "*parameter" and "* parameter" in a function?

Tags: c

Recently for school we had to use specific functions that had a set function and arguments that they wanted for us to use.

However, in every example that I could find prior to the assignment the structure remained the same. The assignment required void `GetIntArray(int *outputArray, int * count)` as one of the functions.

I was really confused by the difference between `*outputArray` and `* count`; do they work the same or does the space between `*` and `count` make a difference?

Comment: No functional difference whatsoever.

Comment: They are both pointers. the only difference is the underlying type of data they point to. In C (along with most other programming language) white space is largely ignored

Comment: The same difference between `if (a == b)` and `if (a==b)`

Comment: `foo(int *bar)`, `foo(int* bar)` and `foo(int * bar)` are all the same thing.

Comment: @joshmeranda err.. read your comment closely again, especially the second sentence.

Comment: Most importantly pick one style and stick with it. Or follow the style from the style guide of whatever code base/company you are working with.